# iPhone SDK - NSDateFormatter - NSDate from string always returns nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So this sounds like it should be so simple, yet for me, this code block returns a `nil` date:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *newStartDate = [df dateFromString:@"2012-05-11 20:45:00"];
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing `newStartDate` to be returned as `nil`? `df` is valid, the format string appears to be valid. I'm completely stuck here, so any advice would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change `hh` to `HH`. `hh` is for 1-12 with AM/PM `HH` is for 0-23.

Answer (score -2):

you should use a valid date

its better if you take something like

`NSDate *d = [NSDate date];`

or it should be 2012-05-11 20:45:00 +0000

your current static date is missing timezone

Comment: ok, thanks for pointing it out
I Don't unerstand why people voted down it, If this kind of culture continues i fear tomorrow may even fear to answer questions